# Can I compile with Cython through a normal Python script?

Tags: python, cython

Cython can sometimes remarkably decrease computational time by converting the code and running it in C. Is there a way to use Cython through a normal script by using some import-- function?

I downloaded Python (x y) and am not even sure what the 'best' way is to use Python. iPython notebook or Spyder etc ... ?

**What are my other options**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your cython code in your .pyx file.

Then use [pyximport](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-pyximport) to compile it by adding something like:

```
  `import pyximport;     
   pyximport.install()` 
   from foo import foo # finds foo.pyx automatically
```

It detects changes in a cython file and recompiles if necessary or else loads the cached module.

A simple example running from ipython in the same directory as my `fib.pyx`:

My `fib.pyx` looks like:

```
def cython_fib(int n):
    cdef long i,a, b
    a,b = 0,1
    for i in xrange(n):
         a,b = b,a + b
    return a
```

Then I import pyximport etc..

```
In [1]: import pyximport 

In [2]: pyximport.install()
Out[2]: (None, <pyximport.pyximport.PyxImporter at 0x7f0139916e10>)

In [3]: from fib import cython_fib # import like a normal python import

In [4]: cython_fib(20)
Out[4]: 6765
```

Comment: Thank you Padraic. And I would then write my program in the .pyx file and only use a .py file to run?

Comment: yes, it basically imports it as a pure python file. I will add an example in a few minutes.

Comment: Another question. What is the most common way of coding python? i.e. with an IDE like Spyder or with iPython notebook or notepad++ etc? I say most common because I'm sure different ways are better for speciffic applications, but surely there is an industry standard?

Comment: I imagine ipython is  pretty widely used, you can run cython files without compiling using ipython also using the extension cythonmagic. Which IDE you use is completely subjective, it is personal preference mostly.